# SVN access issue

Tags: svn

I followed the [document](http://queens.db.toronto.edu/~nilesh/linux/subversion-howto/) for setting up the SVN with Apache [section 3 but not using SSL right now], I can access the "test" repository when I don't enable security settings such as Require user in the httpd.conf. After adding the security settings in the httpd.conf, it prompt for user credentials, though I am giving the right user and password (harry/harryssecret) it is not working.

### Httpd.conf

```
<Location /svn>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
 DAV svn
 SVNParentPath /u01/svn/repositories/
# Access control policy
 AuthzSVNAccessFile /u01/svn/conf/users-access-file
 Satisfy Any
 Require valid-user
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Veera Subversion repository"
 AuthUserFile /u01/svn/conf/passwd
</Location>
```

### file path

```
[svn@mercury conf]$ pwd
/u01/svn/conf
[svn@mercury conf]$ ls
passwd  users-access-file

[svn@mercury conf]$ cat passwd
veera = test
[users]
 harry = harryssecret
 sally = sallyssecret
[svn@mercury conf]$ cat users-access-file
[/]
*=
harry=w
[test:/]
harry=w
```

### error.log from httpd

```
[Wed Jul 10 22:59:57.889044 2013] [auth_basic:error] [pid 14211:tid 1163790656] [client 192.168.0.39:50612] AH01618: user harry not found: /svn/test
[Wed Jul 10 23:01:57.243014 2013] [auth_basic:error] [pid 14239:tid 1165687104] [client 192.168.0.39:50616] AH01618: user veera not found: /svn/test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthUserFile` should be an Apache password file, created using the `htpasswd` binary.

You have given Apache a Subversion password file and it doesn't contain any valid user/password combinations in the appropriate format for Apache.

Comment: I have created now password file using htpasswd but now I am getting Unable to access to Reposiotry at Url xxxxxx/svn/test'. Access to xxxx/svn/test' forbidden

Comment: I gave rw permission, it works